# C# how to parse JSON with SimpleJson library

Tags: c#, json, parsing, unity-game-engine

How to parse JSON string like this "[\"login\",{ \"key\":\"value\"}]" to strong typing variable using SimpleJson library?

Comment: You need a class into which you may deserialize your json.

Comment: Use `JArray arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>("[\"login\",{ \"key\":\"value\"}]" );` to deserialize it using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `SimpleJson.TryDeserializeObject` method. An instance of an anonymous type is placed in the variable `obj`, which describes the structure of the JSON object.

[image: SimpleJSON]

Comment: How i can access these values? obj[1] doesnt work

Comment: You can cast to a `JsonArray` type or use the generic version (it can throw an exception): `JsonArray array = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<JsonArray>("[\"login\",{ \"key\":\"value\"}]");`